# Django Web App Deployment on Render.com, Import Errors

Tags: python, django, deployment, backend, render.com

I am currently trying to deploy my Django Web App to https://render.com/, but I got several problems,
I am following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AgTr5mw4zdI,
at 19:00 I have to import dj_database_url
I have imported the Package in my Virtual Environment!
This is what pip list says

[image: pip list]

Here is my folder stucture:

[image]

I think the problem is possibly because of the folder structure.
Here is the Import

[image: import]

Comment: Restart your editor, or reselect your env in the vscode menu (bottom right bar)

Comment: This doesn't worked

Comment: try downgrading **dj-database-url** to `dj-database-url==1.2.0`

Comment: This doesn't worked too, but here is the exact Import Error:
Import "dj_database_url" could not be resolved from source Pylancereport (MissingModuleSource)
(module) dj_database_url